# Dynamically resize UILabel to content

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

So I have a UILabel that I use to display some piece of text retrieved from a JSON object. Hence I do not know in advance the length of text. Coming from Android development I've been spoiled with the `"wrap_content"` parameter that will automatically adjust the layout according to the text that a textView shows.

In Xcode I seem to be limited to specifying the number of lines a UILabel can display and that's pretty much it. Is there a better, more dynamic way of doing it?

Comment: Try to google for "ios autolayout"

Answer (score 0):

A `UILabel` resizes to its content by default.

You can specify the maximum number of lines (0 for unlimited).